# sharepoint 2013 how usage analytics reports create and what is the mechanism of it?

Tags: 2013, search, enterprise-search, analytics

1. In SharePoint 2013 how usage analytics reports create and what is the mechanism of it?
2. How enterprise search service works in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 1):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spblog/2014/04/03/sharepoint-2013-usage-analytics-the-story/;
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219554.aspx
Usage analytics is a set of analyses that receive information about user actions, or usage events, such as clicks or viewed items, on the SharePoint site. Usage analytics combines this information with information about crawled content from the Search analyses, and processes the information. Information about recommendations and usage events is added to the search index. Statistics on the different usage events is added to the search index and sent to the Analytics reporting database.
A default set of usage events is defined out of the box. The default events are always registered and analyzed by SharePoint. You can also configure custom event types. For more information about the default usage events, see The usage events used by Usage analytics.